# Java: Breaking the recursion when reaching a false

Tags: java, recursion, return

I am writing a program that recursively searches a string for the letters A, T, C or G. Using Pattern and Matcher the first letter of the string is compared against a regular expression. If the first letter matches, the recursive function is called again however cutting the first letter that already matched.

A sequence like ATTAFCG in the example should immediately return a false and stop checking the rest once it hits F, but I found that it does stop there but the return still is a true value. My console output is:

```
Value to return: true Where the letter is: A
Value to return: true Where the letter is: T
Value to return: true Where the letter is: T
Value to return: true Where the letter is: A
Status: true
```

Even after forcing to return a false when m.find() returns a false, the final return value still is a true. What am I doing wrong ? Is it that when a wrong letter is reached the recursion goes back and at last uses the value for the very first letter (true) ? Below is the used code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sequence = "ATTAFCG";
    boolean found = recursive(sequence);
    System.out.println("Status: " + found);
}

public static boolean recursive(String input) {
    boolean returnValue = true;
    String pattern = "^[ATGC]*$";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    String[] list = input.split("");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(list[0]);

    if (input.length() > 1) {
        if (m.find() == true) {
            recursive(input.substring(1));
        } else if (m.find() == false) {
            returnValue = false;
            return returnValue;
        }
    } else if (m.find() == true) {
        returnValue = true;
    } else if (m.find() == false) {
        returnValue = false;
        return returnValue;
    }
    System.out.println("Value to return: " + returnValue + " Where the letter is: " + list[0]);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: you want `return recursive(...)`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this using recursion *and* regexes? Why not just `return !Pattern.compile("[^ACTG]").matcher(input).find();`?

Comment: Note:- you should use `if(m.find())` and `if(!m.find()` instead of `m.find() == true` and `m.find() == false` :Not the problem cause, just it's better

Comment: Note that calling `m.find()` multiple times moves on to the next match on each invocation. You might want to store `m.find()` in a variable.

Comment: @mritunjay or even `else return m.find()`

Comment: @krad what is the output you expect?

Comment: Got it working thanks to a combination of your suggestions, thank you !
First of all: @ AndyTurner 's point about m.find() moving was right, storing it in a variable and comparing the values showed a difference. Second of all: @ Mritunjay 's point about the logic was a good one as well, using the saved variable mentioned earlier on to check the condition made it clearer. Last of all: the code still didn't properly return the right value until I implemented @ Kevin Esche 's return recursive(...) instead of just calling it.

Comment: The updated code is as following:

`public static boolean recursive(String input) {
        String[] list = input.split("");

        String pattern = "^[ATGC]*$";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(list[0]);
        boolean found = m.find();

        if (input.length() > 1) {
            if (found) {
                return recursive(input.substring(1));
            } else if (!found) {
                return found;
            }
        } else {
            return found;
        }
        return found;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
//...
    if (input.length() > 1) {
            if (m.find() == true) {
                returnValue = recursive(input.substring(1));
            } else if (m.find() == false) {
                returnValue = false;
                return returnValue;
            }
//...
```

the problem is that once you recursively call the method you don't set the `returnValue` to its result (which you should have done)

Also I would rather flip the logic in your code, I think it's not good to initialize boolean to `true`